# Socket.Bind() throws "Invalid parameters" exception

Tags: c#, mono

I am developing a Linux application with Mono and stumbled into this. I want to create an IP socket to communicate locally with other processes, but the Bind method fails with a not-helpful message. I have written a sample file that showcases this problem. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    private static EndPoint EP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 23515);
    private static Socket Server;

    private static void InitServer()
    {
        Server = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        Server.Bind(EP);
        Server.Listen(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Server started.");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            var handler = Server.Accept();
            string data = null;

            while (true)
            {
                var bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length = handler.Receive(bytes);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, length);

                if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + data);
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitServer();
    }
}
```

And here is the exception message:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Invalid arguments
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end) <0x407e6910 + 0x000ef> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Test.InitServer () <0x407bc270 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Test.Main (System.String[] args) <0x407b9d50 + 0x0000b> in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Invalid arguments
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end) <0x407e6910 + 0x000ef> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Test.InitServer () <0x407bc270 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Test.Main (System.String[] args) <0x407b9d50 + 0x0000b> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is not a Unix endpoint. Use `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` instead.

Also, there's no reason to use raw sockets. Just use `TcpListener`/`TcpClient`.